# Insert de c# con access

Tags: c#, .net, base-de-datos, ms-access-2010

Tengo un error con el insert a la base de datos de Access, cuando ejecuto el programa y lleno todos los campos y doy clic en guardar me aparece que se guardó correctamente y no me muestra ningún error en la excepción, y cuando voy a ver en la base de datos me doy cuenta que no aparece el dato guardado, el Insert lo he hecho de varias formas con querys y con el dataset de vs.

Quisiera saber por qué no me muestra los datos en Access, y tampoco me sale error de que algo esta mal.

Este es el código que estoy utilizando con el query, y también lo he hecho con el data set y no me permite hacer la inserción en Access:

```
int identificacion = (int) cbIdentificacion.SelectedValue;
int categoria = (int) cbtipoTercero.SelectedValue;
DateTime fecha = DateTime.Today;
String estado = "activo";
try {
    //crear conexion
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\andresfelipe\Desktop\Melonada\Melonada\BD\Melonada.accdb");

    //conectar a la bd
    con.Open();

    //query
    String sql = "INSERT INTO Tercero VALUES('" + this.txtIdentificacion.Text + "'," + identificacion + ",'" + 
                 this.txtNombre.Text + "','" + this.txtPrimerApellido.Text + "','" + this.txtSegundoApellido.Text + "','" + 
                 this.cbSexo.Text + "','" + this.txtTelefono.Text + "','" + this.txtCelular.Text + "','" + this.txtDireccion.Text + "'," + 
                 categoria + ",'" + fecha + "','" + estado + "');";
    OleDbCommand comando = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
    comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

    MessageBox.Show("El usuario se ingreso satisfactoriamente");
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show("no se ingreso" + ex.ToString());
}

// ese es del dataset:
this.terceroTableAdapter1.InsertTercero(this.txtIdentificacion.Text,
identificacion, this.txtNombre.Text, this.txtPrimerApellido.Text,
this.txtSegundoApellido.Text, this.cbSexo.Text, this.txtTelefono.Text, 
this.txtCelular.Text, this.txtDireccion.Text, categoria, fecha, estado);
```

Comment: Hola por favor puedes mostrar el código en el que persistes con la Base de Dados.

Comment: Podrás por favor agregar el código?

Answer (score 1):

Recomendaria es que uses parametros cuando realizas el insert

```
 string connstring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\andresfelipe\Desktop\Melonada\Melonada\BD\Melonada.accdb";
 using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connstring))
 {
    con.Open();

    string sql = "INSERT INTO Tercero (identificacio, tipoidentificacion, nombre, ...) VALUES(@identificacion, @tipoIdentificacion,@nombre, );";

    OleDbCommand comando = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@identificacion", txtIdentificacion.Text);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipoIdentificacion", identificacion);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", txtNombre.Text);

     //resto parametros

    comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Ademas lo recomendable seria que definas los nombre de los campos, ya que si por alguna razon estos cambian de orden se vera afectada el insetrt que definas.

Imagine que el combo de identificacion seria relacionado con algun tipo que se permite seleccionar